# Get details of device on LAN

Tags: android, ip, mac-address

I have written code to scan my local network and get the ip addresses of each device.  However, what I need to do is get some details of the devices connected.  Actually I only need to find out the type of device (printer/phone/computer) etc.  Is it possible to do this from an ip address?  or from the mac address of those devices?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
CAN ANYONE PROVIDE ANY DIRECTION ON THIS ONE?  I JUST NEED TO FIND OUT WHAT TYPE OF DEVICES ARE ON THE NETWORK...I AM CLUELESS IN THIS AREA SO I'M BANGING MY HEAD AGAINST A WALL AT THE MOMENT

Comment: Just by looking at the IP or MAC address you won't be able to. You'll need to poll the devices for information.

Comment: @CustomX ok, sorry but this side of things is completely new.  Would you have any info for me on how I would do that?  I'm just trying to find out if a device is a printer

Comment: I'm not able to help you with that. But I'd guess you need use a protocol (SNMP?) to poll devices for information.

Comment: @CustomX ok thanks anyway, I can't believe there isn't a simpler way to identify other devices on the same network

Comment: @CustomX I can get the ip's for all devices on the network, do you know how I would get the corresponding port numbers? I'm looking at snmp and I need these too

Comment: I don't think Port numbers will help. They won't help you identify devices. You could enter the IP address in a web browser and see what that does?

Comment: I have been looking at snmp4j here: http://www.jayway.com/2010/05/21/introduction-to-snmp4j/  In this they set up a SNMP client with ip and port number so I'm guessing I'd have to do this for each ip address and their corresponding port numbers